# Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $app ]] in class Illuminate\Support\Manager

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to implement Laravel without templates in a minimal fashion. Actually I would like to migrate a Non-Laravel project and do it step by step.

```
require_once __dir__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Application($_ENV['APP_BASE_PATH'] ?? dirname(__DIR__));

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class,
    App\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$request = \Illuminate\Http\Request::capture();
$app->instance('request', $request);

$app->bootstrapWith($this->bootstrappers);

$app->boot();
```

Everything works fine except for the bootstrapper:

```
\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterProviders::class,
```

Which will load `Illuminate\Support\Manager`. By digging a bit I found that `Manager`'s constructor is:

```
public function __construct($app)
{
    $this->app = $app;
}
```

And Laravel cannot resolve the dependencies of `$app`. However if I monkey patch this constructor with the following, then it works.

```
public function __construct(\Illuminate\Foundation\Application $app)
```

How does Laravel resolve the dependency injection for `$app` and why isn't working in my case?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This refers to this Laravel [issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/26766) which is not an issue :)

Don't ask me why, but you are probably missing the following provider:

```
Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class
```

Comment: Thanks nowox, this wasn't in the upgrade guide!

Comment: Save my day, twice :)

Answer (score 2):

I also had the sam approach as yours. I excluded non default packages and upgraded and got same error.

You must add

> Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class

to your

> config/app.php

file.
In my case that worked.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `$this->app` outside the context of a class. I'm surprised that doesn't throw up an error. The lines you copied are within the Kernel class that you're trying to execute outside the context of a class

Comment: Oh ! Sorry, this is my mistake.. I did some copy/paste to write the question. I fixed it